# What is the best way to handle replication save conflict documents in Lotus Notes databases?

Tags: lotus-notes

We have a number of databases that we have replicated to two or more servers within our company.  The reason for the replication to the other servers is the users are located at the other locations which are out of state and could possibly be out of country.

When users are approving or processing the documents, the documents are sometimes displaying as a save-replicate conflict document.

How can we best handle this so that these no longer display in that manner and that the detail is not lost?

Thank you in advance for the information.

Jean

Answer (score 1):

The best way, IMHO, to deal with replication conflicts is to design your application so that they won't be created. I.e., instead of saving the approval or processing information directly in the main document, save it in a new response document. Then if you want to have that information stored in the main document, you can run an agent on just one server to merge the fields from the response into the main and then delete the responses. Of course, if you're using digital signatures you won't want to delete them - but you can use lookups in computed fields or an embedded view in the main document in order to show the information from the responses without actually merging.

Answer (score 1):

We use the old free good [Tool for Replication Conflict resolution](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/tool-conflict). After installation you have a smart icon to start it. When you see a replication conflict just select the original document and the replication conflict, click the smart icon and it will open a window which shows the differences in documents.

You could also buy the [Lotus Notes/Domino Replication Conflict Solver](http://www.ytria.com/WebSite.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_scanEZ_ConflictSolveren) from Ytria which allows you a quick merge of both documents.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the form is set to merge conflicts.

Now. Check your documents for which fields are causing the conflict. There is most often a field created for this in the conflict. Can't remember the name at the moment.

When you identified which field is causing most of the conflics you should redesign your form so that this field do not cause the conflict.

In many notes applications conflicts are caused by fields that is populated on every save. I.e log or workflow log fields.

If this is the case you should move these logs to response documents or to a seperate document type.

Hope it helps